# return a view to ajax post request error in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, view

I want to return html code(by return a view) to my ajax request in laravel 5.3 when click the button:

```
<button type="button" name="button" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getTutor()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
```

here is the function getTutor:

```
function getTutor(){
    $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/findTutor",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                'subjects': $("#subjects").val(),
                'city_id': $("#city_id").val(),
                'districts': $("#districts").val(),
                'job': $("#job").val(),
                'gender': $("#gender").val(),
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()
            }
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }).fail(function () {
            console.log(status, error);
        });
}
```

The route:

```
Route::post('/findTutor','PagesController@findTutorResult');
```

The function findTutorResult in PagesController:

```
    public function findTutorResult(Request $request){
        // dd($request);
        $gender = $request->gender;
        $job = $request->job;
        $city_id = $request->city_id;
        $districts = $request->districts;
        $subjects = $request->subjects;

        $resultProfiles = Profile::when($gender,function($query) use ($gender){
            return $query->where('gender', $gender);
        });
        $resultProfiles = $resultProfiles->when($job,function($query) use ($job){
            return $query->where('job', $job);
        });
        $resultProfiles = $resultProfiles->when($city_id, function($query) use ($city_id){
            return $query->whereHas('city', function ($query) use ($city_id) {
                $query->where('id', $city_id);
            });
        });
        $resultProfiles = $resultProfiles->when($districts, function($query) use ($districts){
            return $query->whereHas('districts', function($query) use ($districts){
                $query->whereIn('id',$districts);
            });
        });
        $resultProfiles = $resultProfiles->when($subjects, function($query) use ($subjects){
            return $query->whereHas('subjects', function($query) use ($subjects){
                $query->whereIn('id',$subjects);
            });
        });
        $resultProfiles = $resultProfiles->get();
        // return $resultProfiles->toJson(); // oke
        return View::make('tutor.resultSearchProfiles', ['resultProfiles' => $resultProfiles])->render();
    }
}
```

When return the resultsProfile, it works fine, but I want to return html code in view resultSearchProfiles. It always: 500 internal sever error. I am newbie in Laravel, thank you!

Comment: remove the line `dataType: "json",` since you are not returning json anymore

Comment: looks like your view has problem

Comment: I chang my view to just contains some charaters, but It still error

Comment: Have you tried @Steve's solution? What's the error?

Comment: Yes, I try. But It still error. When i return a string, array, or json, It works fine, but when i return a view (contain some character(not code)), 500 internal error

Comment: You understand that it will be impossible to answer your question with the provided details. If it's throwing a 500 error, it means that, somewhere (most likely on the view) PHP is throwing an error). You should post the PHP error and should look at the view, because you can have undefined variables or some simple mistake. Or post the view..

Comment: can you enable debug and get the error message from laravel.

Comment: I fixed, I changed View:make() to view(), and clear dataType:json, it works. Thank you